# text-align: center для дива в ие

Tags: html, css

В верстке (html5)

```
   <footer>
        <div id="copyright">
            <span>&copy; 2000-2005 Company Name.</span><br>
            <span>All Rights Reserved.</span>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

для дива с id="copyright" задано text-align: center

```
    /*Футер*/
footer{
    display: block; 
    position: relative;
    width: 775px;
    height: 95px; 
    background: url(/images/footer.png) no-repeat center top;
    margin: -42px 0 0 0;
}

footer #copyright {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin: 59px 14px 0 0;
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

известное дело, в ие сдвигается по центру не содержимое дива, а сам див.
Как можно прописать в таблице стилей для ие, чтобы по центру выравнивалось содержимое?

Comment: Этот баг у меня в ие9 и ие8, в ие7 все отображается как надо.

Answer (score 1):

Создаем новые теги для IE

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script>
      var e = ("article,aside,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section,time").split(',');
      for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        document.createElement(e[i]);
      }
     </script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: да есть у меня там такой код, вернее, не совсем такой, вот этот скрипт подключен http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js, но он выполняет аналогичное действие. 
причем тут это-то?

Comment: У меня одинаковое отображение в ие7 и фф

Comment: да, а в ие9 и ие8 сдвигается по центру не содержимое дива, а сам див.